# Function for finding all possible choices

Tags: matlab

I need the function for finding all possible subset choices, for example:

```
a=[1 3 4 7 8];b = nchoosek(a,3);b =

 1     3     4
 1     3     7
 1     3     8
 1     4     7
 1     4     8
 1     7     8
 3     4     7
 3     4     8
 3     7     8
 4     7     8
```

I need all possible subsets like:
4 3 1,7 3 1,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`perms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html?refresh=true) if the order of the outputs matters. Each permutation will be a new row in the result. Then you can grab the first `k` columns and find the unique rows.

```
a = [1 3 4];
k = 2;

%// Generate all permutations of the index values corresponding to the input
%// We use the index rather than the values of a to ensure that they are unique
P = perms(1:numel(a));

%// Select the first k columns and find the unique rows
P = unique(P(:,1:k), 'rows');

%// Now grab these elements from a
b = a(P);

%//     1     3
%//     1     4
%//     3     1
%//     3     4
%//     4     1
%//     4     3
```

Comment: can `perms` pick only three items out of the list of 5 though?

Comment: i mean n!/(n-k)! not all n!

Comment: @Suever Working for a mentalist badge? :-)